# How to assign different colored speech bubbles for different users in an Instant Messaging application

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, user-interface, frontend

If you were developing an instant messaging application which allows group chat (lets say 3+ people), and each speech bubble needs to be a different color, how would you go about doing this? Is there specific logic out there that can be used to change a specific CSS speech bubble class based off of a users User ID or Session ID? Like for instance if lets say the last digit of each ID ranges from 0-9 and 10 separate CSS speech bubble classes each with different colors were placed in the same css file, would something like this be feasible? I do realize the logic would be flawed if the digits were the same for 2 or more users. Is there a simpler and more intelligent approach? Like assigning a different token to the first user, then second user, etc Is there something that can be done all with CSS selectors? Am curious how one would tackle this task! Your comments/answers are very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
window.setInterval(function(){
    var initialowner = $(".currentonlineuser").html();
    var container = $(".chatbox").html();
    if(container.length){
        $('.chatboxmessage .chatboxmessagefrom').each(function(){
            var df = $(this).html();
            var origin = $(this);
            var chatowner = df.slice(0, -1);
            if(chatowner == initialowner){
                origin.next().css('box-sizing', 'border-box').css('position', 'relative').css('background', '#95c2fd').css('background-image', '-webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.15, #bee2ff), color-stop(1, #95c2fd))').css('background-image', '-webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #bee2ff 15%, #95c2fd 100%)').css('background-image', '-moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #bee2ff 15%, #95c2fd 100%)').css('background-image', '-ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #bee2ff 15%, #95c2fd 100%)').css('background-image', '-o-linear-gradient(bottom, #bee2ff 15%, #95c2fd 100%)').css('background-image', 'linear-gradient(bottom, #bee2ff 15%, #95c2fd 100%)').css('border', 'solid 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)').css('-webkit-border-radius', '3px').css('-moz-border-radius', '3px').css('border-radius', '3px').css('-webkit-box-shadow', 'inset 0 8px 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.65), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2)').css('-moz-box-shadow', 'inset 0 8px 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.65), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2)').css('box-shadow', 'inset 0 8px 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.65), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2)').css('margin-bottom', '5px').css('padding', '3px 3px').css('color', '#000').css('text-shadow', '0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.8)').css('word-wrap', 'break-word').css('z-index', '1');
            }
            else{
                origin.next().css('box-sizing', 'border-box').css('position', 'relative').css('background', '#7acd47').css('background-image', '-webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top,color-stop(0.15, #ace44b),color-stop(1, #7acd47))').css('background-image', '-webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #ace44b 15%, #7acd47 100%)').css('background-image', '-moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #ace44b 15%, #7acd47 100%)').css('background-image', '-ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #ace44b 15%, #7acd47 100%)').css('background-image', '-o-linear-gradient(bottom, #ace44b 15%, #7acd47 100%)').css('background-image', 'linear-gradient(bottom, #ace44b 15%, #7acd47 100%)').css('border', 'solid 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)').css('-webkit-border-radius', '3px').css('-moz-border-radius', '3px').css('border-radius', '3px').css('-webkit-box-shadow', 'inset 0 8px 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.65), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2)').css('-moz-box-shadow', 'inset 0 8px 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.65), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2)').css('box-shadow', 'inset 0 8px 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.65), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2)').css('margin-bottom', '5px').css('padding', '3px 3px').css('color', '#000').css('text-shadow', '0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.8)').css('word-wrap', 'break-word').css('z-index', '1');
            }
        });
    }
    else{
        alert("not found");
    }
}, 100);
```

use this code, it will help, it works for me.